# Specify folders to merge with git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, merge

I have built a Rails application in a Linux environment but spent the last 2-3 weeks converting the application to work in a Windows environment for production (not my idea, I assure you).

I am using git and now have two branches of the same application, one that is configured to use jRuby on Windows with IIS8 and a MSSQL Server backend and the other which uses Ruby, a WEBrick app server and sqlite3 database for development/test.

I would like to continue using the linux environment for dev and test but will need to then combine my findings into my Windows branch.

I am hoping there is a way to create a branch using my linux environment, make changes to my app/ folder (which contains the brunt of the application) and then merge only those changes into my Windows branch. The issue here being if I merge normally, I will overwrite my files configured for Windows.

There are only a few main files I do NOT want merged with my Windows branch:

- Gemfile
- config/applciation.rb
- config/initializers/assets.rb
- config/database.yml

to name a few.

Does anyone have any idea how I might do this?

Comment: This is a wrong approach. The right approach would be to write conditionals in the files above, and load whatever is supposed to be loaded in differrent environments.

Comment: That... Makes so much sense. Let me give that a shot. However.. Have you any idea if the above is possible? Just for reference?

Comment: In any ruby you might just write `if RUBY_PLATFORM` (or `platforms :mri` in Gemfile.) In `database.yml` there should not be any conflict, just specify your MSSQL in `production:` section.

Comment: Thanks for that but wondering also if my original question is possible too?

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to run dev/test as Ruby and production as jRuby? I suppose there's no real gain there.. it's just that my dev/test environment is set up for Ruby at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to cherry-pick relevant commits. Another solution would be to have a core-repo and a repo for each plattform that you support and use `git submodules` to incoperate core.

But I agree with @mudasobwa, using configuration to switch implementation is much simpler and cleaner.